# Error converting data type varchar to float

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

```
CASE
WHEN (Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)- FLOOR(Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)))> 0 AND (Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)- FLOOR(Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)))<=0.25 THEN (0.25+FLOOR(Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)))

WHEN (Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)- FLOOR(Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)))> 0.25 AND (Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)- FLOOR(Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)))<=0.50 THEN (0.50+FLOOR(Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)))

WHEN (Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)- FLOOR(Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)))> 0.50 AND (Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)- FLOOR(Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)))<=0.75 THEN (0.75+FLOOR(Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)))

WHEN (Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)- FLOOR(Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)))> 0.75 AND (Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)- FLOOR(Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)))<1 THEN (1+FLOOR(Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)))


WHEN (Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)- FLOOR(Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)))= 0 THEN (0+FLOOR(Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)))

END

AS Estimated_Effort_Days,
```

The above code is currently rounding up a field called totaleffort to the nearest.25, for example if i have a value of 78.19 it will round up to 78.25.

I have a new requirement for the value of zero, when the value = 0 then i need to display the text 'unknown number' I have attempted to add an additional case statement however the query fails to run with an error :

> Error converting data type varchar to float.

Does anyone have a reccomendation for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your present code returns a *number*. And you are trying to add a condition when it should return a *string*. The problem is, numeric types take precedence over string types, and so, as a result, SQL Server will try to convert your string message to a number (and fail).

To avoid that, you should make sure that all numeric values you are returning are properly converted to strings, *then* you can easily add whatever message you want as a substitute for zeros.

Another thing is, your rounding technique seems to me overcomplicated. If you want to round up, just use [`CEILING()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189818.aspx). If you want to round up to the nearest `0.25`, you can multiply by 4, apply `CEILING()`, then divide by 4.

Here's my attempt at illustrating what I mean:

```
WITH data (totaleffort) AS (
  SELECT CAST(123.5 AS float) UNION ALL
  SELECT 88 UNION ALL
  SELECT 0.067 UNION ALL
  SELECT 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 9608.14
)
SELECT
  ISNULL(
    CAST(CAST(NULLIF(CEILING(totaleffort * 4 / 7.40) / 4, 0) AS decimal(10, 2)) AS nvarchar(30)),
    'unknown number'
  )
FROM data
```

Output:

```
------------------------------
16.75
12.00
0.25
unknown number
1298.50
```

You can also see that I'm using [`ISNULL()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) and [`NULLIF()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) here to replace `0` with a custom text. It works like this:

- the calculation result is passed to `NULLIF` whose second argument is `0` – that means that if the result is `0`, `NULLIF` will return `NULL`, otherwise it will return the result;
- now `ISNULL` does the opposite: it returns the second argument if the first one is `NULL`, otherwise it returns the first argument.

So, with this chain of transformations a zero effectively becomes `'unknown number'`.

Answer (score 2):

you can't expect to have a column where sometimes the value is varchar and and other time float, so you can convert the whole results in THEN to nvarchar like:

```
CASE
    WHEN (Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)- FLOOR(Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)))=0 
    THEN cast('unknown number' as nvarchar)
    WHEN (Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)- FLOOR(Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)))> 0 AND (Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)- FLOOR(Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)))<=0.25 
    THEN CAST((0.25+FLOOR(Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar))) as nvarchar)
```

look at last line

Comment: is it giving the same error or are you not getting the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to add when the value of your condition is 0, them do it like this:

```
CASE

WHEN (Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)- FLOOR(Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)))=0 THEN 
"unknown number"


WHEN (Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)- FLOOR(Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)))> 0 AND (Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)- FLOOR(Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)))<=0.25 THEN (0.25+FLOOR(Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)))

WHEN (Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)- FLOOR(Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)))> 0.25 AND (Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)- FLOOR(Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)))<=0.50 THEN (0.50+FLOOR(Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)))

WHEN (Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)- FLOOR(Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)))> 0.50 AND (Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)- FLOOR(Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)))<=0.75 THEN (0.75+FLOOR(Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)))

WHEN (Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)- FLOOR(Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)))> 0.75 AND (Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)- FLOOR(Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)))<1 THEN (1+FLOOR(Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)))


WHEN (Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)- FLOOR(Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)))= 0 THEN (0+FLOOR(Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) as nvarchar)))

END

AS Estimated_Effort_Days,
```

Comment: Still getting the error:
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 2
Error converting data type nvarchar to float.

Comment: Try it again with my edit. If it doesn't work, put all the query (or sp if it's the case) in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
WHEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)) - FLOOR(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(totaleffort/7.40)))) = 0 THEN  'unknown number'
```

An observation:

why dont you change `(expression) > 0 and (same expression) <=0.25`
to  `(expression) between 0 and 0.25`

on the first example you are calculating the same expression twice for no reason

Answer (score 0):

I notice that both the provided answers are doing a conversion in the 'When' part of the clause without converting the comparison value to nvarchar as well.  That may be why you are still seeing errors with the provided code.

I would suggest that you leave the data type alone in the 'When' clause (it appears that the 'correct' comparison is numeric), but all the 'Then'/'Else' results need converted to character types as SQL can't mix-and-match data types in the same column.

Just a little extra input...beyond the scope of the question, I realize :-) If this is for a report, I suggest altering the report interface instead of altering the SQL.  Leaving the data type alone at the view/procedure/function level will make the data structure more reusable/extensible and calculations/aggregates that *should* use the zero value will behave as expected without having to 'reverse convert'.  If you must change the SQL-side instead of the interface-side, I would suggest including both the 'report pretty' and 'actual value' columns in the SQL-side structure so you don't lose any functionality by removing zero values and changing data types.